# The same forwards and backwards, What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, palindrome

Read forwards or backwards I'm the same

Remove my last two letters I sound like a single letter

Without my first two letters I'm trivial and sound like I'm an animal

Leave only my second and fourth letters and we both come first

What am I?

> I have no Cs, but I love the sea

Comment: A nice little puzzle - did you come up with it or hear it from someone else?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I write all my riddles, but I have seen other anagrams before, so I came up with the riddle, but not the concept.

Comment: ...actually palindrome, not anagram - updated tags.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Well I saw an anagram and it gave me the idea, so I guess the idea was similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is it

> Kayak

Read forwards or backwards I'm the same

> It is a Palindrome

Remove my last two letters I sound like a single letter

> Removing last a & k, it sounds like 'k'(kay)

Without my first two letters I'm trivial and sound like I'm an animal

> Without first k & a, it is yak(animal)

Leave only my second and fourth letters and we both come first

> Second and fourth letter, both are A,first letter of alphabet series (I did  interpret it wrong. Thanks @JonathanAllan)

I have no Cs, but I love the sea

> Sea Kayak

Comment: Yes this is the answer!

Comment: One of the first on here I figured out as well. Really nicely worded question and answer :)